# Target "build" does not exist in the project for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm checking out code for a project where contributors use different dev tools for coding in C sharp (C#). My .csproj file was manipulated by someone using Sharp develop and now I get 'The target "build" does not exist in the project'.

- How can I correct this?

I am using Visual Studio 2008 SP 1.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

If you were to do it manually, I would take all the files and add them back to a new project file one by one.

Comment: Yep, I should have thought of that first.

Comment: I tried this and it still gave me the same build error.

Answer (score 177):

The accepted answer is a workaround, not a solution. You need to open the `.csproj` file for editing in a text editor and ensure the following line is present in there

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

If not add it to the end.

*Note: For VS2008, this may be `$(MSBuildToolsPath)`*

Comment: In case of SharePoint 2007 project that uses the *stsdev.exe* utility adding `<Import Project="DeploymentFiles\Microsoft.SharePoint.targets" />` in the *.csproj* file may help.

Comment: I was having the same issue but on a Xamarin.Android project. The import that works for this kind of issue is `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />`.

Comment: Given how often one has to edit the .csproj you'd think Visual Studio would provide a right-click option to do it.

Comment: What to do for a F# project I'm trying to build with MS VS 2019 Build Tools ?

Answer (score 6):

Just had this issue with Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.2 and wiping out the `.vs` folder in the solution root was the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: I just had this when transferring an ASP.NET MVC 5 project from my older personal development machine to a new one I just bought, using Visual Studio 2019 16.9.4 on the new machine, and VS 16.9.3 on the old machine. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when I upgraded a project built in VS2005 to VS2010 Express. Initially the VS2010 refused to load the project with error message "Project is not supported by this installation". After trying many solutions finally it worked and my guess is it worked when two lines were removed from the project file that related to build target. However it presented a new problem that the project would not build. Of course this makes sense as I removed the entries from project file that told Visual Studio how to build the project.

Finally got hold of another project that was working on VS2010 Express and copied following lines to the project that was failing. It worked after that.

```
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

Deleting the .vs folder worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

As for me, I was trying to build a solution with F# projects (.fsproj files).

The problem was that I was using an old MSBuild (located in path `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe`).

When I tried to run the new version, located in `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"`, everything started working fine.

Or in case you're using Visual Studio Enterprise, or GithubActions CI, then the path is `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"`.

I found them by running this:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -find MSBuild\**\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```