# Service fabric VSTS Continuous Integration using Hosted Agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines

I updated my service fabric VSTS continuous integration build process to the latest as mentioned in the [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-set-up-continuous-integration/).

According to the updated document now we can use Hosted Agent as build agent. But build failing at second step with the following error

> The target "Build" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Service Fabric Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.ApplicationProject.targets (112,11)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
>   SFProject\SFProject\SFProject.sfproj(0,0): Error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project.
>   Project "C:\a\1\s\SFProject\SFProject.sln" (1) is building "C:\a\1\s\SFProject\SFProject\SFProject.sfproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
>   C:\a\1\s\SFProject\SFProject\SFProject.sfproj : error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project.

[image]

I tried all answers found on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035414/target-build-does-not-exist-in-the-project-for-visual-studio) , but no solution working.

Comment: Open your .sfproj and check the value of the ProjectVersion property.  If it's 1.0, you'll need to upgrade to the latest version of the Service Fabric SDK and then upgrade your project once that's been installed.

Comment: thanks for the answer, Build succeeded. As you said I updated the Service Fabric SDK to latest version. After that VS2015 shown a popup to upgrade the Project, the value of the ProjectVersion property is upgraded to v1.1.

Comment: Ok, I'll add this as an official answer.

Comment: As Matt Thalman said you have to Install latest version of Service Fabric SDK in your PC and Upgrade your service fabric project after that checkin the code to VSTS. Now try Queue Build, It should get succeed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like the .sfproj project file is an older version.  By opening the .sfproj in a text editor and checking the ProjectVersion property, you can determine the version.  Starting with project version 1.1, which is the version produced by Service Fabric SDK 2.1, NuGet packages were introduced for building the project.  The NuGet package is what provides support for building the project in the hosted build agent.  So you'll need to make sure you've installed Service Fabric SDK 2.1 or higher and then upgrade your .sfproj by opening it within VS before attempting to build it in VSTS.